# How do I play local SWF files in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome, flash, browser, swf

today I just upgrade my ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

The problem is that I cannot play local swf files.

Even after installing flash player you cannot play swf files.

I can play online flash games in browser but not swf files when you have them downloaded in your computer

Any fix for this problem?

I tried gnash but that won't open swf in browser so the data that I have saved in cookies for that specific swf file won't restore.

This problem is same for all browsers I have tried. (chrome, chromium, firefox)

what I have tried is this command:
   `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install`
and this one:
   `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound`

just installed flash plugin for chrome still not fixed this is what I did: downloaded a tar file from adobe then these 3  commands:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins
sudo cp –r usr/* /usr
```

the internal flash player for chromium is activated:
[image]

and also I tried gnash which didn't open my file.
you can download the swf file from this site: http://autoevony.jimdo.com/      there is a free version

Temporary solution for this problem is to upload your swf file to a website (then you can view it from browser). I use [bitbucket.org](http://www.bitbucket.org)